# Auto-scroll to active horizontal element when not in view, within a container, after the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, horizontal-scrolling

I've created a JSfiddle for a horizontal scrolling navigation element: https://jsfiddle.net/sstracy/goe8j3sv/

Visually, it loads on the page just as I want it except for when the establishing active nav item is too far from the left, smaller screens will hide the active link. Once the page loads, I would like the horizontal nav to scroll to the right, until the active item is visible. Otherwise, the functionality is working just as I want it.

For this testing stage, all the links within the nav do not go anywhere but in the final version, they will direct users to different pages, all pages with the same base navigation code. The only difference will be that each page will have a specific body tag Class that will match the ID provided in each nav link.

I know the code isn't the cleanest as I have started working with a mix of JS and jQuery here... so a solution utilizing either is fine.

I have started some code to hopefully get the nav to scroll but it isn't working:

JS Lines 146-158:

```
// Scroll if selected item is not in view when the page loads but not after or during user interaction.
            var ids, matches = document.body.className.match(/(^|\s)hpn-(\d+)(\s|$)/);
            if (matches) {
                // found the id
                ids = matches[0];

                var $elem = ids;

                var navPosition = $('#pnProductNav').scrollLeft(),
                    elemPosition = document.getElementById(ids).offset().left;

                $("#pnProductNav").animate({scrollLeft: navPosition + elemPosition}, 800);
            }
```

- First, I'm finding a Class from the body div that starts with "hpn-".
- If there is a body Class that matches, I put it in a variable "ids" and then "$elem".
- I'm then trying to find the distance the link element is from the left so that I can animate a scroll to the right. **This is where I believe I'm falling short because the navigation bar does not scroll on page load, while the link "Racks" or "hpn-19" is the active link.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I am happy to answer any questions to clear anything up, before help is provided!

Comment: You have `$links is not defined` on line 311 (line 153 in the JS frame of Fiddle). You should check the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). ;)

Comment: Thanks for that. It was leftover code from something else I was trying. I've made the "correction" and deleted that line but I'm still getting errors... because I'm obviously doing something wrong and cannot figure it out. :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was really just over-thinking this one. I finally got it:

```
    // Scroll if selected item is not in view when the page loads but not after or during. 
    // First, find and get body class name that starts with hpn-
    var ids, matches = document.body.className.match(/(^|\s)hpn-(\d+)(\s|$)/);
    if (matches) {

        // found the id so define it
        ids = matches[0];

        // Get position of the nav bar and the position of the link with the matching ID
        var navPosition = $('#pnProductNav').scrollLeft(),
            elemPosition = $('#' + ids).offset().left;

        // Add the two together to get your scroll distance and animate    
        $("#pnProductNav").animate({scrollLeft: navPosition + elemPosition}, 800);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sstracy/goe8j3sv/12/